# How to switch resource files in asp.net mvc based on db data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, localization

For example if i have a languages table in the db, which contains culture id (LCID) and short name of a language, then in my view i have a dropdown where user can select either english language or french language. I have 2 Resource files in GlobalResources folder Resources.resx and Resources.fr.resx. Where english language is main.

Where i am stuck, is switching of languages itself, because i need a way to make a "connection" between Resource.resx and Resource.fr.resx files with cultureId or short language name from DB.

If it were possible to attach a cultureId (LCID) to a resource file it would be great, because then i just had to choose the file with the right LCID, but it doesnt seems possible.

I could ofcourse look for the Resource file with the "correct" short name and just pick it, but it seems like there should be better solutions.